# nginx deny user agent causes error when not encapsulated in quotes

Tags: nginx, configuration, server-setup, deny

I'm trying to deny some user agents I constantly see probing my `nginx` web server.

If I have this in my `.conf` file

```
 ## Block http user agent - morpheus fucking scanner ##
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (morfeus fucking scanner|ZmEu)) {
       return 403;
    }
```

I get the following error when starting services:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid condition "$http_user_agent" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/siteXXX:19
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

If I place quotation marks around it, it starts but doesn't deny as I would expect it to.

```
 ## Block http user agent - morpheus fucking scanner ##
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "(morfeus fucking scanner|ZmEu)") {
       return 403;
    }
```

Any ideas?  Im looking for a case-insensitive user agent deny.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just drop the brackets and add quotes:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "morfeus fucking scanner|ZmEu") {
    return 403;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what is the string you are trying to match?

Regex should be in quotes, but if you want to match regex special symbol (,),| - you need to  escape it with \

try this:
`$http_user_agent ~ "(morfeus fucking scanner)|ZmEu"`